# How to work with Specific Columns in Data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am switching sources for my trade algorithm so i can work with intraday stock data. Previously, I used Morningstar which was built into the Pandas-Datareader which allowed for easy manipulation of data. Now that I am using AlphaVantage for my source, I am wondering how I can access specific columns and work with the data in the specific columns. When i try to set a variable = to a column index, it returns an error 'tuple must be integer or slice, not tuple'. I am wondering how i can access each column using pandas?

```
alpha = ts.get_intraday(symbol='AAPL', interval='1min',outputsize= 'compact'
Close = alpha[0]
```

Comment: Might I suggest that you improve your title, making it a little more specific? Perhaps something like "How do I access specific columns and data using Pandas?" It also might be helpful if you provide applicable error message(s).

Comment: Yes i just updated it. Thank you